# Bib page number in my index and bibtitle distance from the top

Tags: page-numbering

I've got two last questions.
The first one is about the wrong page number for my bibliography in the table of contents.
I've already tried the solution with `\cleardoublepage` and `\phantomsection` before or after my `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}`, but I can't obtain anything good.
So I tried also the solution with `tocbibind` package, but in this case I lost some others properties of my bibliography.
I give you my code for the bibliography, so you can understand better my situation:

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\bf\Large{REFERENCES}\vspace{-20pt}}    
\begin{flushleft}
\bibliographystyle{phd}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\makeatletter\def\@biblabel#1{#1.}\makeatother
\bibliography{References}
```

I'm using book class.
My second problem is more simple I think.
The title of my bibliography (References) is farther from the top of the page than the other titles of my work. How can I correct this distance?

Ok.I'm sorry for my late. Here is part of my code. I hope it's helpful:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,epsf,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[pdftex,dvips]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.jpg}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[italian,english,german]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\advance\leftmargin\labelsep}
  {\labelsep=0.7cm \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}{}{}

\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,top=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{3pt}

\def\listofsymbols{\input{symbols} \clearpage}
\def\addsymbol #1: #2#3{$#1$ \> \parbox{6.5in}{#2 \dotfill \pageref{#3}}\\} 
\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{fancy}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

\newenvironment{abstract}[1][italian]
  {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{fancy}
   \iflanguage{italian}{}{\selectlanguage{#1}}
   \vspace*{\fill}
   \begin{center}
   \bfseries\Large\MakeUppercase\abstractname\vspace{12pt}
   \end{center}}
  {\par\vfill}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\include{Title}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\renewcommand*\abstractname{SOMMARIO}
\begin{abstract}        %Sommario
\normalsize\emph{Tanto va la gatta al largo che ci lascia lo zampino}
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand*\abstractname{ZUSAMMENFASSUNG}    
\begin{abstract}[german]        %Zusammenfassung
\normalsize\emph{Wenn die Katze geht zu viel zu verraten, kann verlor seine kleine Hand}
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand*\abstractname{ABSTRACT}   
\begin{abstract}[english]       %Abstract
\normalsize\emph{If the cat goes too much away, can lost its little hand}
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand\contentsname{\bf\Large{TABLE OF CONTENTS}\vspace{-20pt}}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{\bf\Large{LIST OF SYMBOLS}\vspace{-20pt}}
\listofsymbols

\selectlanguage{english}

\mainmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\include{Introduction}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\include{Chapter1}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\include{Conclusions}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\bf\Large{REFERENCES}\vspace{-20pt}}    
\begin{flushleft}
\bibliographystyle{phdpisa5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\makeatletter\def\@biblabel#1{#1.}\makeatother
\bibliography{References}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

I don't know if this part of my code could be considered as a MWE, but I tried to leave the most important part of the code.
With this code I'm obtaining the "REFERENCES" title farther from the top of the page than the usual distance of any other title. And in the Table of Contents, I have two times the word "REFERENCES", the first one at the wrong page (6 in my case) and the second one at the right page (7 in my case).

Comment: Rather than code snippets, provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. BTW, the `\addtocounter` could well be the cause of your first problem.

Comment: I don't know in this case how is the best MWE to explain my problem. I can give you all my tex code, if you think could be a solution.

Comment: Not many helpers at tex.sx are interested to delve into huge anounts of code. By trimming your code to a manageable MWE (that still shows the problematic behaviour!), you'll increase the likelihood that someone is helpful.

Comment: @lockstep I've answered in the GuIT forum where the same question was posted.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to reproduce the error that you mention (about the line "References" showing up twice in the table of contents). Have you considered eliminating the instruction

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

from the code? The reason I ask is that some other style files you load may already be inserting a similar line somewhere in the process. Just a thought.